# Conditional style on PrimeReact DataTable cells

Tags: javascript, reactjs, primereact

I am using Prime React and trying to color code the text of each cell in my data table based on a set of conditions. The style is not displaying correctly. Here is my code:

```
import './App.css';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { classNames } from 'primereact/utils';
import { DataTable } from 'primereact/datatable';
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';
import 'primereact/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css';
import 'primereact/resources/primereact.min.css';
import {FilterMatchMode} from 'primereact/api';
import {InputText} from 'primereact/inputtext';

function App() {

  const [resolution, setResolution] = useState('1d');
  const [model, setModel] = useState('sma');
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    global: {value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS}
  });

  const proxyUrl = ""
  const endpoint = "";

  function refreshData() {
    fetch(proxyUrl+endpoint+"?resolution="+resolution+"&model="+model)
        .then(res => {
          if (!res.ok) { // error coming back from server
            throw Error('could not fetch the data for that resource');
          } 
          return res.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          setData(JSON.parse(data['model']));
          setError(null);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          // auto catches network / connection error
          setError(err.message);
        })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    refreshData();
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    refreshData();
  }, [resolution, model]);


  const stockBodyTemplate = (rowData) => {
    const stockClassName = classNames('border-circle w-2rem h-2rem inline-flex font-bold justify-content-center align-items-center text-sm', {
        'bg-green-100 text-white-900': rowData.Sma_Score === 3,
        'bg-red-100 text-white-900': rowData.Sma_Score === -3,
        'bg-yellow-100 text-white-900': rowData.Sma_Score === 1,
        'bg-yellow-100 text-white-900': rowData.Sma_Score === -1
    });
    return <div className={stockClassName}>{rowData.Sma_Score}</div>;
};


  return (
    <div className="App">

      <br/>

      <label for="resolution">Resolution</label>
           <select name="resolution" required="required" type="text" placeholder="1d" onChange={(x) => setResolution(x.target.value)}>
           <option value="1d">1d</option>
          </select>
          <br/>
          <br/>

      <label for="model">Model</label>
           <select name="model" required="required" type="text" placeholder="sma" onChange={(x) => setModel(x.target.value)}>
           <option value="sma">SMA</option>
          </select>
          <br/>
          <br/>

      <InputText onInput={(e) =>
          setFilters({
            global: {value: e.target.value, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS}
          })
        }
        />
      
      {(model === 'sma') && (
        <DataTable value={data} sortMode="multiple" filters={filters} paginator rows={25}>
        <Column field='Symbol' header='Symbol' sortable/>
        <Column field='Name' header='Name' sortable/>
        <Column field='Category' header='Category' sortable/>
        <Column field='Sma_Score' header='Score' body={stockBodyTemplate} sortable/>
        <Column field='Date' header='Date' sortable/>
        </DataTable>
      )}

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I pulled this example from the documentation [React Prime Conditional Colors](https://codesandbox.io/s/7weihb?file=/src/demo.js:561-568) and tried to customize it for my use case but it's not displaying any new styles on render. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: Can show show what is your data in the state and how the table look like? Based on current code it looks like you are trying to customise the Score column.

Comment: I solved it. I needed to install primeflex then import a few dependencies into my index.js file